# trying to insert div in wordpress slider code

Tags: php, html, wordpress, slider

I have bought a wordpress theme and now i am trying to insert my own div into the code of the slider. I am not very good with wordpress and here you can see my website: http://nw.flamboyance.nl/

on the slider you see a grey block which has this code: `<div class="vak '.$align.'"></div>`. that is the div I already inserted but the problem is, that the text on it is actually not between `<div class="vak '.$align.'"></div>` with the result that the text is jumping off the grey block by zooming out or in..That is ugly..

here you see a part of the slider code(and my div is before the `<h2>` tag):

```
foreach( $slider_elements['elements'] as $keys ){
foreach( $keys as $key=>$slider ){
    if($slider['img'] != null ){
        $img = cuckoo_get_attachment_all_size( $slider['img'] , 'full');
        $align = $slider['title_aling'] ? $slider['title_aling'] : '';
        $color = $slider['font_color']  ? $slider['font_color'] != '#' ? 'style="color:'.$slider['font_color'].';"' : '' : '';
        $lineColor = $slider['line_color']  ? $slider['line_color'] != '#' ? ' style="background-color:'.$slider['line_color'].';"' : '' : '';
        $line = $slider['slide_title'] != '' && $slider['slide_subtitle'] != '' ? '<span class="slide-title-line"'.$lineColor.'></span>' : '';

        $title = $slider['slide_title'] ? '<div class="vak '.$align.'"></div><h2 class="slide-title '.$align.'" '.$color.'><span class="titspan">'.cuckoo_echo_for_wpml(THEMENAME.' Homepage Slides #'.$key, 'Slide Title', preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n|\r)/','<br/>', $slider['slide_title']), 0). $line.'</span></h2>' : '';
        $subtitle = $slider['slide_subtitle'] ?  '<div class="slide-subtitle '.$align.'" '.$color.'>'.cuckoo_echo_for_wpml(THEMENAME.' Homepage Slides #'.$key, 'Slide Subtitle', preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n|\r)/','<br/>', $slider['slide_subtitle']), 0).'</div>' : '';
        $button = $slider['url_button_slides'] ? '<div class="slide-button '.$cuckoo_button['main-slider-button'].' '.$align.'"><a href="'.$slider['url_button_slides'].'" title="'.cuckoo_echo_for_wpml(THEMENAME.' Homepage Slides #'.$key, 'Slide Button Title', $slider['title_button_slides'], 0).'" class="slide-button">'.cuckoo_echo_for_wpml(THEMENAME.' Homepage Slides #'.$key, 'Slide Button Title', $slider['title_button_slides'],0).'</a><span class="button-back"></span></div>' : '';

        $slides .= "{ image : '".$img."', title : '". $title . $subtitle . $button ."' }," ;
    }
}
```

}

The $Title, $subtitle and $button shows up on the slider on the left and right side..how can i put this between `<div class="vak '.$align.'"></div>`?

Sorry if i am not clear, i would gladly explain it again.
Pleasy help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `div` was simply added to the beginning of the string represented by the `$title` variable.

```
$title = $slider['slide_title'] ? '<div class="vak '.$align.'"></div><h2 class="slide-title '.$align.'" '.$color.'><span class="titspan">'.cuckoo_echo_for_wpml(THEMENAME.' Homepage Slides #'.$key, 'Slide Title', preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n|\r)/','<br/>', $slider['slide_title']), 0). $line.'</span></h2>' : '';
```

As a result that `div` will only ever be displayed were ever that variable is being outputted.

If you wanted all of these items to be displayed within this wrapper div then you are going to need to find where they are being displayed within the theme.

It appears that this code is eventually defines some JavaScript variables on page for a plugin called... `supersized`

```
jQuery(".super-homepage").supersized({..});
```

This plugin seems to be working on a specific element.

```
<div id="supersized-container" class="super-homepage">

    <!--Arrow Navigation-->
    <div id="prevslide" class="fullwidthslider-prev button-style-1"><a class="load-item"></a><span class="button-back"></span></div>
    <div id="nextslide" class="fullwidthslider-next button-style-1"><a class="load-item"></a><span class="button-back"></span></div>

    <!--Time Bar-->
    <div id="progress-back" class="load-item">
        <div id="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>

    <!--Slide captions displayed here-->
    <div class="container message screen-large">
        <div id="slidecaption"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="supersized-loader" class="slidePreloadImg">
        <div class="img-loader"></div>
    </div>
    <!--Control Bar-->
    <div id="controls-wrapper" class="load-item">
        <div id="controls">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could either add those classes manually to the outter most div... or have your div wrap all of the above outputted HTML.

I hope this guides you in the right direction.

#### Edit

Chage this section:

```
$slides .= "{ image : '".$img."', title : '". $title . $subtitle . $button ."' }," ;
```

To... this

```
$slides .= "{ image : '".$img."', title : '<div class=\"vak ".$align."\">". $title . $subtitle . $button ."</div>' }," ;
```

Comment: if i wrap it all in my div i won't move left and right because my div also has an $align variable

Comment: This last edit by @ductiletoaster might be the best answer. Try it out.

Comment: It is still not working :(. i dont see the slider anymore.

Comment: @FFBbodie my answer was close it is just causing a JS error. Try my most recent edit

Comment: I see the slider with the grey box but not the text :(

Comment: To be honest that is now a CSS issue. Your Right/Left align classes for some reason are causing the text to be pushed off page. My gave you the solution for your question... if you now have a question regarding CSS that  should be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can achieve this is by adding a hidden div, give it a class, and let it be the container of whatever the `$align` is. Set this to the beginning of `$title`:

```
$title = $slider['slide_title'] ? '<div class="algin_info" style="display:none">' . $align . '<div>...
```

Then once all your script is loaded, create a script that wraps these boxes, then looks for that class you create to retrieve the align info like so:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $box = $("#slidecaption");
        var align = $box.find(".align_info").text();
        $box.wrapInner("<div class=" + align + "></div>");
    });
</script>
```

EDIT:

This is a variation of what the other answer gave you, but they had some syntax errros. Try this out:

Replace this:

```
$slides .= "{ image : '".$img."', title : '". $title . $subtitle . $button ."' }," ;
```

with this:

```
$title_content = "<div class='vak $align'>$title  $subtitle  $button</div>";
$slides. = "{'image': '$img','title': '$title_content'},";
```

Comment: shouldn't the variable not be .$align. instead of +$align+?

Comment: http://nw.flamboyance.nl/ it is not working very well. i replaced the div and placed the script in the same file but above the html code.. i am going to edit the post. i will put the whole script then you can see what i mean

Comment: its ok.. did you try the last EDIT submitted by @ductiletoaster?

Comment: You need Jquery for the code I provided to work. place this right before the script: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: maybe i can help you remotely. Ever used www.join.me?

Comment: i have never used www.join.me but i would like to try it.

Comment: ok go to that website, click on the orange button, run the app, then it will give you a code, let me know what those digits are so I can connect

Comment: Please wait a sec. I am currently working on @ductiletoaster solution

Comment: @CodeGodie I already gave him a solution for the DIV issue. However, now the text is hidden due to some CSS issues. He should ask a separate question since now this is going beyond the scope of his original.

Comment: i have installed join me on which button should i click to run?

Comment: Guys, thank you very much for your help! it works but indeed i have a CSS issue but the text is not hidden. it is just shoved out of the screen. the div has a position absolute style.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work as you need to supply us with more information on that slider you are using, but I would try the following:

```
$title = $slider['slide_title'] ? '<div class="vak ' . $align . '"><h2 class="slide-title ' . $align . '" ' . $color . '><span class="titspan">' . cuckoo_echo_for_wpml(THEMENAME . ' Homepage Slides #' . $key, 'Slide Title', preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n|\r)/', '<br/>', $slider['slide_title']), 0) . $line . '</span></h2>' : '';
$subtitle = $slider['slide_subtitle'] ? '<div class="slide-subtitle ' . $align . '" ' . $color . '>' . cuckoo_echo_for_wpml(THEMENAME . ' Homepage Slides #' . $key, 'Slide Subtitle', preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n|\r)/', '<br/>', $slider['slide_subtitle']), 0) . '</div>' : '';
$button = $slider['url_button_slides'] ? '<div class="slide-button ' . $cuckoo_button['main-slider-button'] . ' ' . $align . '"><a href="' . $slider['url_button_slides'] . '" title="' . cuckoo_echo_for_wpml(THEMENAME . ' Homepage Slides #' . $key, 'Slide Button Title', $slider['title_button_slides'], 0) . '" class="slide-button">' . cuckoo_echo_for_wpml(THEMENAME . ' Homepage Slides #' . $key, 'Slide Button Title', $slider['title_button_slides'], 0) . '</a><span class="button-back"></span></div></div>' : '';
```

This will add the opening `<div class="vak ' . $align . '">` to the start of `$title` and the closing `</div>` to the end of `$button`

Comment: your code does not work :(. the result is that the text on the slider will be gone...I have a javascript file but it is big and i don't know where the part of the slider is..how can i provide you the code of the slider? is it possible to put a file here? am not often on stackoverflow

Comment: where did you get the plugin from? do they have a website?

Comment: did you buy this theme? where from?

Comment: This is a chuckolove theme with a fullscreen slider. i bought this at https://creativemarket.com/CuckooThemes/66386-CuckooLove-Wedding-WordPress-Theme

Comment: check out my other answer